# Can I install TeXLive on Windows 7 just by copy/paste (without affecting the system/registry)?

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I want to install TeX Live 2014 on a notebook with Windows 7 Professional installed on it for testing something (performance).

However I do not want to change something in the system registry, so

- is it possible to install and use TeX Live on Windows 7 just in one path without doing any changes to the registry or other system directories?

(Background: the notebook is from my work and I do not want to change/damage anything there or mess up/blow up the system somehow.)

Comment: Did you try? The answer here is 'yes' as TeX Live doesn't use the registry: you'll only need to add it to your (personal) path.

Comment: I didn't want to try before being sure for the above mentioned reasons (added in myedit)

Comment: If it's a work system and you are worried, you should probably get permission for any changes even copy-paste ones.

Comment: @JosephWright: thanks. I'll ask for permission, however I'll get it easier if I can confirm that no harm is done to the system. :-) So that means if I follow the general installation instructions https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html , there will be only files be copied to one path on my system?  Then *if you write it as an answer, I'll happily accept it*.

Comment: there is portable installation that make no change https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed in https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html, TeX Live does very little on installation to affect the running of a Windows system (or indeed any other). The TeX Live tree itself is self-contained, and so you can just copy it in its entirety from another system to say `C:\texlive\2014` (for the current release). Almost certainly you'll want to then add it to your personal path: in the Control Panel, search for 'environmental variables' and then add a new variable `PATH` for your user with value #(say) `C:\texlive\2014\bin\win32` (if there is already a personal `PATH`, add this new value to the end using a `;` separator). The installer can be run in 'single user' mode, and will do the above for you. It adds very little to the registry, primarily the option to uninstall.

As [noted in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/can-i-install-texlive-on-windows-7-just-by-copy-paste-without-affecting-the-sys?noredirect=1#comment555763_234609), there is also a p[ortable version of TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2) which changes the path only on a 'on-the-fly' basis and can be run without even copying the files onto the local system.

Comment: Summary of comments so CW.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine tried that with TexStudio and it did not work properly. Basic editing and viewing was fine, but compilation didn't do anything, but that was because they migrated from one machine to another.

More generally, if you are concerned that installing a piece of software will damage your system then you should not install it, and you should certainly not install it but avoiding the installation instructions, since that will make it near impossible to uninstall it correctly. If you haven't already, take backup of your system. Prove the backup works by deleting and then restoring something unimportant. Then you can install your software (properly!) and if you don't like the results and the uninstall doesn't do what you think it should, then you can restore your backup.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.